# version.h not found, headers already installed

Tags: c++, linux, header-files

I am attempting to build the v41-dvb driver. I have used: `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to install the appropriate headers for my kernel, but I still get the error: `"fatal error: include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory"`

I have checked, and version.h does exist in several locations.

I have searched this site and everywhere else I can think of, but I am still getting the error. Can anyone help?

Comment: You said `version.h does exist in several locations.`, what are they?

Comment: Did you add a parameter to your compilation that sets the directory where included files are found?